# Does AdMob SDK used in my app collects any user personal information

Tags: android, admob

In my Android application I use AdMob to preview Ads in my application, using the code below:

```
    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And in Google Play I received questions to accurately rate my application, such as:

> Does the app share user-provided personal information with third
>   parties? Learn more
>
> Does the app share the user's current physical location to other
>   users?

In my code I don't share any of my user's info with AdMob, but does AdMob SDK collect any user personal information as location, name, region, etc. to preview a targeted Ads?

Also I need to know how to control (Or at least to know) the Ads maturity level previewed in my application by AdMob, so I can set the right maturity level for my app in Google Play?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In my code I don't share any of my user's info with AdMob, but does
>   AdMob SDK collect any user personal information as location, name,
>   region, etc. to preview a targeted Ads?

Both the questions you've quoted from Google Play start with **Does the app...** (which means is your code explicitly doing something against policy. If you are not, you can go ahead and mark both as **No**. Admob Sdk is Google owned and you do not need to worry about them voilating their own ploicy. They obvoiusly won't. If you are using any third party network libraries in your app, read their documentation and make sure they are not collection any such information which **personally identifies** the user. If they are then and then only mark it as **Yes**.

> Also I need to know how to control (Or at least to know) the Ads
>   maturity level previewed in my application by AdMob, so I can set the
>   right maturity level for my app in Google Play?

1. Goto `Admob` Site
2. Goto `Monetize` Tab
3. `Select an app` from the left
4. Click on `Allow and block ads`
5. Select and unselect categories you want to show or not show from the `General Categories` and `Sensitive Categories` tabs.

And that is also where you check what kind of ads are displayed by default and you have an option to change them.

It looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank your for your help, regards my second question "Does the app share the user's current physical location to other users?" I'm using Facebook share dialog which gives the user the ability to share his location while making a post, though and based on your amazing and clear answer, this is not my application responsibility and my answer also should be no, Am I right?

Comment: Does the app permit the public sharing of nudity or graphic violence?

Is all content that may be inappropriate for young children (i.e., profanity, hate speech, racial slurs, violence, gore and sexuality) proactively blocked or prevented such that the app would be considered child-friendly?

In my application, the user can share whatever he wants via Facebook share dialog, so what my answers should be?

Comment: Yes, you are doing it with users consent. He had to click post before the info goes out. Hence your app is in compliance

Comment: Those things as you mentioned are on Facebook. Not you app. So no.

Comment: Another question to my latest question, and if (It is) my app offers the user an option to search Facebook for pages and previews the result (Pages pictures), which may contain (for ex) nude or semi nude pictures (If there's such things allowed on FB)? Will my app then considered to be safe for childrens?

Comment: That's a tricky one. You need to take a call. But, from my experience the questions are targeted in content directly displayed on your app. That said, you should be allright since you cannot control what they search for on facebook.

Comment: Then why they rejected my app twice and stated in their email to me: Take the content rating questionnaire again, paying special attention to questions about sexual content. ---- In the second time: Take the content rating questionnaire again, paying special attention to questions about Fill in: gambling, violence, alcohol and drug references, sexual content, social media. Is it possible because I haven't yet set my Ads type in my AdMob account? and not because of Facebook sharing dialog?

Comment: yes, you should block those ad categories if you said no such content is displayed. Ads displayed are app content and you should consider those when answering the questionnaire.

Comment: Knowing that I want my app to be available for everyone has a FB account, which means 13+ ... So I should (remove / disable) Alcohol, Gambling, etc. Ads from my AdMob account. Am I right so far?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100541/discussion-between-virus-and-astrount).

Comment: Citing from the answer: "Does the app... (which means is your code explicitly doing something against policy. If you are not, you can go ahead and mark both as No "
In my understanding it's not as easy as this. All libs and SDK that you package into your app are part of your app, aren't they? And you are responsible for everything that "your app" does.  It's a shame that Google does not provide instructions on how to answer all the questions in Google Play and App Store in a legally safe way. See this for App Store: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/667794